# Recursive Brute Force 0-1 Knapsack - add items selected output

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I am practicing recursive algorithms because although I love recursion, I am still having trouble when there is "double" recursion going on. So I created this brute force 0-1 Knapsack algorithm which will output the final weight and best value, and its pretty good, but I decided that information is only relevant if you know which items are behind those numbers. I am stuck here, though. I want to do this elegantly, without creating a mess of code, and perhaps I am over-limiting my thinking trying to meet that goal.  I thought I would post the code here and see if anyone had some nifty ideas about adding code to output the chosen items. This is Java:

```
public class Knapsack {

static int num_items = 4;
static int weights[] = { 3, 5, 1, 4 };
static int benefit[] = { 2, 4, 3, 6 };  
static int capacity = 10;

static int new_sack[] = new int[num_items];
static int max_value = 0;
static int weight = 0;

// O(n2^n) brute force algorithm (i.e. check all combinations) :
public static void findMaxValue(int n, int currentWeight, int currentValue) {

    if ((n == 0) && (currentWeight <= capacity) && (currentValue > max_value)) {
        max_value = currentValue;
        weight = currentWeight;

    }

    if (n == 0) {
        return;
    }

    findMaxValue(n - 1, currentWeight, currentValue);
    findMaxValue(n - 1, currentWeight + weights[n - 1], currentValue + benefit[n - 1]);

}



public static void main(String[] args) {

    findMaxValue(num_items, 0, 0);

    System.out.println("The max value you can get is: " + max_value + " with weight: " + weight);
    // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(new_sack));

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The point of the 0-1 Knapsack algorithm is to find if excluding or including an item in the knapsack results in a higher value.  Your code doesn't compare these two possibilities.  The code to do this would look like:

```
public int knapsack(int[] weights, int[] values, int n, int capacity) {
  if (n == 0 || capacity == 0)
    return 0;

  if (weights[n-1] > capacity)  // if item won't fit in knapsack
    return knapsack(weights, values, n-1, capacity);  // look at next item

  // Compare if excluding or including item results in greater value
  return max(
    knapsack(weights, values, n-1, capacity),             // exclude item
    values[n] + knapsack(weights, values, n-1, capacity - weights[n-1]));  // include item
}
```

Comment: My code is checking all possible subsets, therefore it is checking if items are included or excluded. That's what all possible subsets means.